# How do you make an optional field and comma in a yasnippet?

Tags: yasnippet

I want to make a snippet for a function with optional arguments.  For example something like:

```
myfunc($1, $2, $3)
```

But in this case, $2 may be optional. I know I can press Ctrl-D to skip it, but it leaves behind the comma. How do I get a snippet to delete the comma if I skip the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by nesting the fields:

```
myfunc($1${2:, $3}, $4)
```

to fill all three, press `A<tab><tab>B<tab>C`.  To skip the middle one, do `A<tab><c-d>C`

Comment: This does not seem to do what I described. When I use this snippet, I would have thought I could press a<tab>b<tab>c<tab> and get myfunc(a, b, c) but there is no comma between b and c. It does work for making two args. e.g. a<tab>b<tab><tab> results in myfunc(a, b).

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake in the original answer.  See the edited one - it should work now.